# Is my proof that the set of all functions from $X' \subseteq X$ to $Y'\subseteq Y$ exist valid

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Firstly we take the power sets of $X$ and $Y$, $2^X$ and $2^Y$ which are always non-empty. We take $\beta\in 2^X$ and $\alpha\in 2^Y$. As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are always sets we can define $\alpha^\beta$ as the set of all function from $\alpha$ to $\beta$. We then use the axiom of union twice getting, 
$$\bigcup_{\beta \in 2^X}\alpha^\beta$$ 
$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in 2^y}(\bigcup_{\beta \in 2^X}\alpha^\beta)$$
This will trivially contain all such functions from $X' \subseteq X$ to $Y'\subseteq Y$ I however am unsure whether my steps are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing works, but it is aguably simpler to note that each of the functions you're interested in is a subset of $X\times Y$, so you can get at set of all of them by using Separation on the power set of $X\times Y$.